# Archives and Categories in Custom Menu

Tags: theme-development, menus, categories, archives

What is the easiest way to place the Archives and Categories lists within my menu under a parent tab. I'd like both of the lists, such as "Archives" leading to the "archives" sub-menu, and the same for Categories. I'm looking for a non-programmatic (admin-panel only) solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The new 3.0 menu will do this for categories, just create a custom link as the 'parent' tab and give it a url of http://# and then add our categories as sub items but it doesn't AFAIK give you a option for dealing with date based archives.

Answer (score 0):

use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and [wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives).

Comment: I'm sorry, @bangbambang, I was looking for a solution through the admin-panel, and not programmatic. I would like (if possible) our non-programmers to be able to do something like this.

Comment: @Jonathan unfortunately I have no idea about any plugin that meet your requirements.There's a plugin named WP Spry Menu but it **only** make list of categories.